# ffmpeg fix not divisible by 2 (401x480) using -filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to fix not divisible by 2 using `-filter_complex` parameter.

Most solutions to fix divisable by 2 use `-vf` but I cant use both in the same command.

```
os.system("/tmp/ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black -i /tmp/2.gif -filter_complex  '[0][1]scale2ref[bg][gif];[bg]setsar=1[bg];[bg][gif]overlay=shortest=1'  /tmp/outBlack2.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert scale filter just before setsar.

```
[bg]scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1[bg];
```